# How many equal circles under particular conditions

Tags: geometry

Let $ C $ be a circle with radius $  r > 0  $ and let $  \alpha$, $  0 < \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2} $,  be an angle   such that  $  \alpha  $ or  $  \frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha  $ is a central angle of $  C  $  subtended by an arc of length $  \sec^3 \alpha $.

a) What is the minimum value of $  r  $ to guarantee that such an angle exists?

b) What values of $  r $ guarantee that exactly two such angles exist?

c) What is the maximum number of such angles that exist for a given $  r $,  and what
is the minimum value of $  r  $ to guarantee the existence of this maximum number of angles?

Comment: So $r\alpha=\sec^3\alpha$?

Comment: Can you give the context ?